# How to open a popup window from an extension

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I have a working extension that allows me to check market prices of steam items.
You basically click the extension and then a prompt box opens and the item is inputted there.
It then opens up a new windows with the search query, displaying the market prices.
I would like to tweak it by displaying the list of items as a popup from the extension, like the default popup.
For that I need to know some stuff:
1) How do I call that popup function within the js code?
2) How do I open it so that it shows only what I need? like [this](http://prntscr.com/39g8jn), instead of showing the whole site.

Here are the codes:

manifest:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CS:GO checker",
  "description": "This extension checks market prices",
  "version": "1.1337",

  "permissions": [
    "http://steamcommunity.com/market/"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
    }
```

popup.js:

```
function test ()
{
    var userInput=prompt("Please enter your item below:");
    if (userInput!=null)
    {
        newwindow=window.open("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q="+userInput,userInput,'height=800,width=670');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(test);
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: I forgot to mention that I'm very new to javascript, so if you have an answer, try to explain it very carefully to me that I could understand.